# What's the deal with this Lambda?

Tags: vb.net, lambda

```
Dim count As Func(Of Integer, Boolean) = Function(x As Integer) x = 1

If (count(GetSelectedCount())) Then
    'Proceed
Else
    MessageBox.Show("You can only select one item at a time.", "Multiple items selected", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
End If
```

GetSelectedCount returns the number of items checkemarked in a grid. It returns 0 when nothing is selected. The Lambda is supposed to return true only when 1 item is selected. The messagebox should only run when > 1 items are selected. I ma getting the messagebox even when no items are selected.

Solution ~ Decided to drop the Lambda and go old school

```
Select Case GetSelectedCount()
    Case 1

    Case Is > 1
        MessageBox.Show("You can only select one item at a time.", "Multiple Selection", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Case Else
        MessageBox.Show("You have no items selected.", "No Selection", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

End Select
```

Answer (score 2):

The = operator pulls double duty for both assignment and equality in VB.Net.  Is it possible it's being interpreted incorrectly as assignment here?  Try this instead:

```
Dim count As Func(Of Integer, Boolean) = Function(x As Integer) Return x = 1
```

Comment: Na, underlined blue with "expression expected".

Answer (score 2):

Your lambda function (checks whether ONE item is selected) and your stated goal (run message box if >1 items are selected) are not mutually exclusive.  Neither covers the case when NO items are selected.

So if no items are selected, then "x=1" is false, so the "If" statement fails and you fall through to the message box.

What about writing

```
Dim count As Func(Of Integer, Boolean) = Function(x As Integer) (x <= 1)
```

??

Comment: underlined blue with "expression expected", but you are correct with the logic